# Do I need to counterbalance 8 audio excerpts to control for order effects?

Tags: counterbalancing

I have 8, 1-minute audio excerpts, all that feature the same music.  Four of them were recorded by a middle school music ensemble (2 expressive, 2 unexpressive) and four by a high school music ensemble (2 expressive, 2 unexpressive).

I am getting participants in the MS ensemble, the HS ensemble, and a set of expert evaluators to listen to all 8 excerpts and assign a single rating.

Because all of these excerpts feature the same 1-minute piece of music (although by two different groups and under two different conditions - expressive and unexpressive), do I need to have 3 different audio presentation orders to help control for order effects?

I am going to average the 2 expressive and 2 unexpressive audio excerpt ratings for each group (MS, HS, Experts).  My thought that was by averaging the ratings (to get scores for each group - MS Expressive, MS Unexpressive, HS Expressive, HS Unexpressive) that I wouldn't really need to do have separate orders.

Any help about counterbalancing and/or ways to avoid fatigue effects (since it is 8, 1-minute excerpts of the same piece of music, although recorded by two different music groups under two different conditions)  would be most helpful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How many people are availble to give a rating? Why 1 minute? Can it be shorter?

You could randomly allocate the order that raters listen to the pieces. Then code each rating by ms/hs; exp/n-exp; order listened to; and rater. Then model the impact of each of these on rating. Hard to say exactly how without more info on the distribution of the ratings.

If you had enough raters and it wasn't too burdensome, you might randomly allocate, with replacement, >>>8 pieces of music listened to by each rater, so that they will listen to the same piece of music more than once. Then you could look at the reliability of ratings, and the impact of fatigue, within people.

Answer (score 0):

Each rater should hear the excerpts in a randomised order.  It doesn't matter if you average scores across raters or across 'expressive' or 'non-expressive' performances, you should still randomise the order.

Also the post above makes a good point about cutting the length of listening time for each excerpt - 1 minute seems too long.  20 seconds might be plenty. This will avoid fatigue